# Disable or prompt VoIP calling on Android Whatsapp

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, whatsapp-messenger, voip

I recently updated my Whatsapp on Android. I noticed that it allows voice calls with the new version. There is a contact that resides in the same city as me that I would like to place a call to. However, Whatsapp doesn't give me the option of making a normal call when I press the call button from within whatsapp, rather than Internet call. I would have to exit the app and call with the normal phone app. Is there an option to disable this or at least prompt which app to use?

I appreciate that Whatsapp coming up with new initiatives, but please allow users choose between Internet or carrier call. Is there a new version that allows this or do I have to wait for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the contact. Open a message thread by tapping,  then tap on the nam/number to view contact. At the top right (on Android) is the menu button. Tapping it brings up the option to 'view in address book'. This is the only way to do it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000016) on Official WhatsApp site for placing a call, it seems that there is no provision at this moment to place NORMAL phone call via WhatsApp.

Because WhatsApp may want to promote their NEW feature (VoIP Calls), they may not have included an option to place NORMAL phone call.

Earlier, since WhatsApp did not have VoIP call feature, it was OK for them to take user to PHONE App and let them place a NORMAL call, but now since WhatsApp itself supports voice calling, they don't want users to use ANOTHER app (Normal PHONE app for ordinary calls).

Just on same note: Check Google's very own Hangout App. When you try to use it for voice calling, it too don't take you to PHONE app to place NORMAL call, neither it gives user option to choose an alternate APP. It simply places a voice call using VoIP!

Comment: But then again, they did not think about times when we don't have data coverage. Its just stupid not to have fallback features.

Comment: AFAIK, No VoIP app (including Google Hangout) allows user to place NORMAL Calls. It's just that earlier WhatsApp did not have voice calling feature, they might have kept an option to place Normal call. But with introduction of VoIP in WhatsApp, I doubt if they will allow normal calling!

Comment: In the developing world, the majority of people have prepaid cards. When they are empty or there is no data network, they can't receive a voip call, but can receive normal calls. If I'm urgently trying to talk to someone and the checks doesn't became marked, I usually call them. Now with this terrible feature, it isn't possible.